# Prims and Bellman-Ford Algorithms in Directed Graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, bellman-ford

Please suggest resources to learn how to find a minimal spanning tree in a directed graph using Prim's algorithm, as well as Bellman-Ford algorithm to calculate the shortest path in a directed graph.

Answer (score 2):

Finding an MST from a directed graph is a different problem, for which you cannot simply adapt Prim's. You should instead use [Edmond's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Liu/Edmonds_algorithm).

[Bellman Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) already works on directed graphs. No need to alter anything.

The links provided should get you started. Google for additional resources if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like some actual code for the algorithms, I recently coded both of these algorithms up.

- [Prim's algorithm](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=prim)
- [Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=bellman-ford)

The comments at the top of these files contains an analysis of the two algorithms both from a correctness and runtime perspective, and I hope they can shed some light on how they work.

Answer (score 0):

The [alsuwaiyel textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=SPx4iHZEOugC&printsec=frontcover&dq=alsuwaiyel&hl=en&ei=gFMOTardAoH88Abz2fXrDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) on Google Books is very good and has most of the book available.